# Find elements in json object by number/order in the list

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making a help command for a discord bot, right now I'm trying to get a list of all the commands from a json file.

The json file looks like this:

```
{
    "command": {
      "help": {
        "name": "help",
        "syntax": "help str",
        "description": "Outputs list of commands or info on a specific command.",
        "example": ">>help, >>help gn"
      },
      "gn": {
        "name": "gn",
        "syntax": "gn int",
        "description": "gn, guess number. Used to guess the secret number, if you get it correct you gain 1 point.",
        "example": ">>gn 22"
      }
    }
  }
```

The code I'm currently trying:

```
jsonobject = JSON.parse(bufferFile('\command.json'));
if (!input[1]) {
    console.log(Object.keys(jsonobject.command).length);
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(jsonobject.command).length; i++) {
        message.channel.send(jsonobject.command[i].description);            
    }
}
```

This should output the description of each command but instead, `jsonobject.command[i]` is `undefined`. I tried outputting `jsonobject.command` and I got `[object Object]`. `Object.keys(jsonobject.command).length` does output the correct number of commands.

Comment: [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `i` refers to a number which is used for iteration and it's not the actual key. So keep an array with keys and get key value using index within the loop.

```
jsonobject = JSON.parse(bufferFile('\command.json'));

if (!input[1]) {
    // heys array
    var keys = Object.keys(jsonobject.command);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        message.channel.send(jsonobject.command[keys[i]].description);            
        // get key from keys array using index --^^^^^----
    }
}
```

---

With ES6 you can make it simpler using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
if (!input[1]) {
    Object.values(jsonobject.command).forEach(({description}) => message.channel.send(description))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was beat by seconds by the first answer, which already explains your issue well. Anyway, here's another approach using `for ... of` (not supported in Internet Explorer, but by all modern browsers).

```js
var jsonobject = {
    "command": {
      "help": {
        "name": "help",
        "syntax": "help str",
        "description": "Outputs list of commands or info on a specific command.",
        "example": ">>help, >>help gn"
      },
      "gn": {
        "name": "gn",
        "syntax": "gn int",
        "description": "gn, guess number. Used to guess the secret number, if you get it correct you gain 1 point.",
        "example": ">>gn 22"
      }
    }
  }

for (var key of Object.keys(jsonobject.command)) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + jsonobject.command[key].description);            
}
```